# select distinct and join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for the most efficient way to write this query...

From table X, i need a selection of unique ids.
From table Y, I need the text that go to those ids

```
SELECT DISTINCT ( x.id )
    FROM x

SELECT y.text
    FROM Y
    WHERE x.id = y.id
```

I know i can do something like this, but really slow

```
SELECT y.text
    FROM Y
    WHERE y.id IN ( SELECT DISTINCT ( x.id )
                        FROM x )
```

I've looked at some of the post about joins, but I'm unfamiliar with them. Any of you Gurus want to show me how this should be done, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Try [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)

Comment: Try `EXISTS` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select y.text from y inner join 
  (Select x.id from x
   group by x.id) x
on x.id = y.id
```

Answer (score 0):

How does this work? Totally off the top of my head...

```
SELECT x.id, y.text FROM x LEFT JOIN y USING (id) GROUP BY x.id;
```